# Programmatically Add Data Breakpoint from C++ in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I need to debug a complex GC written in C++ and there is a lot of aliasing for variables inside the code which makes tracking the value of a specific variable quite difficult. Usually I do this using data breakpoints, but obviously the address changes every debug session and I need to add a breakpoint where the variable is created, get its address, remove the old breakpoint, add the new one, etc. If I multiply this process for several variables it becomes annoying and also time consuming.

Is it possible to add a data breakpoint programmatically?

I've found this answer [Programmatic data breakpoint in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076786/programmatic-data-breakpoint-in-visual-studio-2010), but it's quite old and I hope there is better support for this.

Comment: just an idea but maybe you can make a macro of keyboard shortcuts or use `pyautogui` or something similar

Comment: Do you specifically need Visual Studio Data breakpoints? For a GC, it might make sense to implement your own watch mechanism using [`GetWriteWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-getwritewatch) or [Guard Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-guard-pages)

Comment: @MSalters the fact that it's a GC is most likely not relevant, probably I shouldn't have added that info in the question. I just need to track the value changes for few specific variables during the debugging session in a complex code base with lots of aliasing.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that Visual Studio needs a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41179799/15416) to set these data breakpoints; you can't do that from Ring 3 code. And there are only 4 HW breakpoints so it needs guard page tricks if you have more.

Comment: Visual Studio has an SDK which allows it: `EnvDTE.Breakpoints.Add` but that's for Visual Studio extenstions, not for the program to be debugged.